# PyO3 linker error when using "extension-module" feature

Tags: rust, linker

When I try to build very simple a PyO3 module, the compilation stops at the link stage and returns a very long error message. I compile this code on Linux.

The Rust project looks like this:

```
├ Cargo.toml
└ src/
  └ lib.rs
```

Cargo.toml:

```
[package]
name = "dytest"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[lib]
name = "dytest"
crate-type = ["cdylib"]

[dependencies]
pyo3 = { version = "0.16", features = ["extension-module"] }
```

lib.rs:

```rust
use pyo3::prelude::*;

#[test]
fn test_print() {
    pyo3::prepare_freethreaded_python();
    Python::with_gil(|py| py.run( "print('Hello World')", None, None ) );
}
```

When I now run `cargo test`, I get a linker error:

```
error: linking with `cc` failed: exit status: 1
  |
  = note: "cc" "-m64" [...many, many paths...]
  = note: /usr/bin/ld: /home/user/dytest/target/debug/deps/libpyo3-c98e45c2daa36b66.rlib(pyo3-c98e45c2daa36b66.pyo3.b04632a8-cgu.2.rcgu.o): in function `pyo3_ffi::object::Py_DECREF':
          /home/user/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/pyo3-ffi-0.16.2/src/object.rs:407: undefined reference to `_Py_Dealloc'
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/user/dytest/target/debug/deps/libpyo3-c98e45c2daa36b66.rlib(pyo3-c98e45c2daa36b66.pyo3.b04632a8-cgu.2.rcgu.o): in function `pyo3_ffi::object::Py_None':
          /home/user/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/pyo3-ffi-0.16.2/src/object.rs:472: undefined reference to `_Py_NoneStruct'
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/user/dytest/target/debug/deps/libpyo3-c98e45c2daa36b66.rlib(pyo3-c98e45c2daa36b66.pyo3.b04632a8-cgu.2.rcgu.o): in function `pyo3::err::PyErr::take':
          /home/user/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/pyo3-0.16.2/src/err/mod.rs:264: undefined reference to `PyErr_Fetch'
          
          [...many, many error messages...]

          /usr/bin/ld: /home/user/dytest/target/debug/deps/libpyo3-c98e45c2daa36b66.rlib(pyo3-c98e45c2daa36b66.pyo3.b04632a8-cgu.15.rcgu.o): in function `pyo3::types::string::PyString::to_string_lossy':
          /home/user/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/pyo3-0.16.2/src/types/string.rs:199: undefined reference to `PyUnicode_AsEncodedString'
          collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
          
  = help: some `extern` functions couldn't be found; some native libraries may need to be installed or have their path specified
  = note: use the `-l` flag to specify native libraries to link
  = note: use the `cargo:rustc-link-lib` directive to specify the native libraries to link with Cargo (see https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html#cargorustc-link-libkindname)

error: could not compile `dytest` due to previous error
```

If I replace
`pyo3 = { version = "0.16", features = ["extension-module"] }`
with
`pyo3 = { version = "0.16" }`
everything works, but the [PyO3 User Guide](https://pyo3.rs/latest/print.html) explicitly states this feature.

Trying this code on a Windows machine, works.

I assume I am missing some kind of dependency, but I can't figure out, what is missing.

Comment: It seems that libpython is not loaded properly. Have you tried to add the path to libpython to LD_LIBRARY_PATH? like `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=path/to/your/libpython`

Comment: I tried `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.8.so.1.0 cargo test` but the error remains.

Comment: `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is for _runtime_ execution. Here the error is at _compile_ time. You could try with `LDFLAGS=-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`, or check in the cargo documentation how to pass extra flags to the linker.

Comment: I tried both (setting `LDFLAGS` as well as adding `rustflags = ["-L", "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.8.so.1.0"]` to `.cargo/config.toml`) but the result stays the same.
I also tried it under Ubuntu 20.04 and Debian 11.3. The same result on both OSes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is a known PyO3 issue. It is mentioned in their [FAQ](https://pyo3.rs/latest/faq.html#i-cant-run-cargo-test-im-having-linker-issues-like-symbol-not-found-or-undefined-reference-to-_pyexc_systemerror):

Cargo.toml:

```
[dependencies.pyo3]
version = "0.16.3"

[features]
extension-module = ["pyo3/extension-module"]
default = ["extension-module"]
```

`cargo test` fails with linking errors when the extension-module feature is activated. A workaround is to make the extension-module feature optional and running the tests with
`cargo test --no-default-features`.